# How to create dll in C++ for using in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, serial-port

I've a little question to ask you.

I have one C++ source and one header files. The C++ file uses windows.h library, makes operations using serial port(basic operations: **read(), write()** etc.).

What I want to do is, creating a library using these files, and use that library in my **C#.Net solution**.

What type of library I need to create?
How can I do it?
After creating library, How can I import it to C# solution?

My best regards.

**Code Parts I'm using:**

```
// MathFuncsDll.h

namespace MathFuncs
{
    class MyMathFuncs
    {
    public:
        // Returns a + b
        static __declspec(dllexport) double Add(double a, double b);

        // Returns a - b
        static __declspec(dllexport) double Subtract(double a, double b);

        // Returns a * b
        static __declspec(dllexport) double Multiply(double a, double b);

        // Returns a / b
        // Throws DivideByZeroException if b is 0
        static __declspec(dllexport) double Divide(double a, double b);
    };
}

// MathFuncsDll.cpp
// compile with: /EHsc /LD

#include "MathFuncsDll.h"

#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

namespace MathFuncs
{
    double MyMathFuncs::Add(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Subtract(double a, double b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Multiply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Divide(double a, double b)
    {
        if (b == 0)
        {
            throw new invalid_argument("b cannot be zero!");
        }

        return a / b;
    }
}
```

**C# import part:**

```
[DllImport("SimpleDll.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern double Add(double a, double b);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string a = Add(1.0, 3.0));
}
```

Comment: Do you really need C++ for this? .NET has a SerialPort class...

Comment: I know, but I have to use them.

Comment: You could use `C++/CLI` instead of C#, and then use your code normally.

Comment: @Adban I know sir, but it has to be a part of C# project.

Comment: @Un_NatMenDim: Still you can use what Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz said in your C# project.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After several comments, here a try:

C++ Code (DLL), eg. math.cpp, compiled to HighSpeedMath.dll:

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall math_add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

C# Code, eg. Program.cs:

```
namespace HighSpeedMathTest
{
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("HighSpeedMath.dll", EntryPoint="math_add", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static extern int Add(int a, int b);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int result = Add(27, 28);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, if the entry point matches already you don't have to specify it. The same with the calling convention.

As mentioned in the comments, the DLL has to provide a C-interface. That means, extern "C", no exceptions, no references etc.

**Edit:**

If you have a header and a source file for your DLL, it could look like this:

math.hpp

```
#ifndef MATH_HPP
#define MATH_HPP

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall math_add(int a, int b);
}

#endif
```

math.cpp

```
#include "math.hpp"

int __stdcall math_add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: Simon, that made the trick. Thank you. but, What if I have a header file for my source file? Do I have to add extern "C" again? if so how?
Thank you again...

Answer (score 6):

You need to compile your C++ code into a dynamic link library and do the following in C#:

```
  class MyClass
  {
  [DllImport("MyDLL.dll")]
  public static extern void MyFunctionFromDll();

        static void Main()
        {
              MyFunctionFromDll();
        }
  }
```

Comment: I don't get it, could you pls expand what you mean?

Comment: Which part? You need to create a dll (in this example, the dll is called MyDLL.dll, and declare the function from the dll as showed here (in the example, MyFunctionFromDll())

Comment: Sir, I can't add the library I've created. Visual Studio pops out an error. In additon, I can't use DllImport keyword in my C# solution.

Comment: Guess I need to add using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
So, I don't have to add a library as a referance to use in C# solution? Just using DllImport?

Comment: When I run the project, exception occurs. is says Unable to load DLL.

Comment: This is typically the case if the DLL is at the wrong location, try to put next beside the exe, in the project dir, etc.

Comment: @Simon, I put the dll file in the solution "Solution/CSharpProjectName/bin/Debug".  Now it says Unable to find an entry point 'functionname' in DLL 'dllname'

Comment: @Un_NatMenDim is the function exported? You need to add _declspec(dllexport) in the function declaration.

Comment: Here it is: static __declspec(dllexport) double Add(double a, double b);

Comment: @Luchian Grigore, sir it doesn't have to be. I just use msdn example.

Comment: @Un_NatMenDim why are you calling me sir?

Comment: Are you sure your declaration in the C# class matches the one in the dll: public static extern double Add(double a, double b);

Comment: @Luchian Grigore, just trying to be polite :)

Comment: @Luchian Grigore, in C# call: public static extern double Add(double a, double b); The same ,yes.

Comment: The symbols has to be exported with __declspec(dllexport) AND marked as extern "C" OR by using a *.def File (which is doing both in one). You could use the Dependency Walker to see the exported functions of the DLL.

Comment: @Simon, I used extern "C", but errors occurs. "IntelliSense: linkage specification is not allowed".

Comment: I can't help you without code - probably you have /clr specified in your native DLL?

Comment: Ok.. you have to export free functions, using extern "C". Class functions are not working - P/Invoke requires a C- interface (that means also, you cannot throw an exception).

Comment: @Simon, I've tried to add extern "C"{  },  but errors occurs. "IntelliSense: linkage specification is not allowed"

Comment: Perhaps time to take this to a chat room?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Lichian's offer to compile to a regular DLL and use p/invoke which is probably the simplest way
You can also create your C++ as a COM component (probably something you don't want to do) and the 3rd option you have is to add a thin layer of C++/CLI 
e.g.

```
using namespace System;

namespace youcomany{ namespace CPPWrapper
{
    Wrapper::Function(String^ parameter)
    {
        //call the rest of you C++ from here
        }
}}
```

Comment: Hi sir. Could you please expand? Calling rest of C++?

Comment: it is just that C++/CLI is C++ and you can call whatever you like. create  regular C++ object with new and CLI objects with gcnew

Comment: Generally speaking if you need to pass simple parameters between C# and C++. DLLImport would probably be easier. If you need to pass complex type C++/CLI is easier

Answer (score 1):

You may use [C# DllImport and Dllexport for DLL Interop](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dllimport) walkthrough as a starting point. And here is the [Platform Invoke Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.