# Standard method for creating dll in c++ and calling in delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I am looking for the correct method to create a DLL in C++ and call it in Delphi. I use CodeBlocks for the DLL and Delphi RAD Studio 10.2.

My C++ header and source code for building the DLL as described in [How to create dll in C++ for using in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366590/how-to-create-dll-in-c-for-using-in-c-sharp/8366615#8366615) is as follows:

Main.h:

```cpp
#ifndef MATH_HPP
#define MATH_HPP

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall math_add(int a, int b);
}

#endif
```

Main.Cpp :

```cpp
#include "main.h"

int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall math_add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

This code in CodeBlocks builds `math_dll.dll` without any error.

Calling the DLL in Delphi:

```pascal
function math_add(X, Y: Integer): Integer; stdcall; external 'math_dll.dll' name 'math_add';
```

But when I run Delphi and call this function, I have the following error:

> "the procedure entry point math_add could not be located in the dynamic link library math_dll.dll"

Which part of my code is wrong?

Comment: Search for the error code. There are thousands of hits that tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your note. I edited my post.

Comment: You changed the question completely! This one is a duplicate too. Learn about tools like dumpbin to inspect the contents of PE modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default name mangling for the `__stdcall` calling convention is `_<name>@<bytes_in_arguments>`.  So your DLL function is most likely being exported as `'_math_add@8'` instead of as `'math_add'` like you are expecting.  Use a tool like PEDUMP to verify that.

You can use a [`.DEF` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-def-files?view=vs-2019) when compiling the DLL to change the exported name, or you can update your Delphi `function` declaration to use the correct exported name for the `name` attribute.

Comment: Hi Remy , thank you for response. but I was wrong in error report, my error is :"the procedure entry point math_add could not be located in the dynamic link library math_dll.dll"

Comment: It is true. Thank you.